# Python unittest.TestCase object has no attribute 'runTest'

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x, python-unittest

For the following code:

```
import unittest

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def test1(self):
        assert(True == True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    suite.addTest(Test())
    unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suite)
```

Using Python 3 to execute it, the following error is raised:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 10, in <module>
    unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suite)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/unittest/runner.py", line 168, in run
    test(result)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/unittest/suite.py", line 67, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/unittest/suite.py", line 105, in run
    test(result)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/unittest/case.py", line 477, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/unittest/case.py", line 408, in run
    testMethod = getattr(self, self._testMethodName)
AttributeError: 'Test' object has no attribute 'runTest'
```

But `unittest.main()` works.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You need to invoke a [`TestLoader`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestLoader):

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    suite = unittest.defaultTestLoader.loadTestsFromTestCase(Test)
    unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suite)
```

Answer (score 15):

You have to specify the test method name (`test1`):

```
import unittest

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def test1(self):
        assert(True == True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    suite.addTest(Test('test1')) # <----------------
    unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suite)
```

Or, if you want to run all tests in the file, Just calling [`unittest.main()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.main) is enough:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score -1):

The actual test for any `TestCase` subclass is performed in the `runTest()` method.  Simply change your code to:

```
class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def runTest(self):
        assert(True == True)
```

Comment: Yes, it works. But is there a way to make it work without changing the Test class? @bhajun-singh.

Comment: Just say `pass` instead of `assert(True == True)`

Comment: This [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html) seems to say otherwise.  To wit:

"Each instance of TestCase will run a single base method: the method
named methodName. In most uses of TestCase, you will neither
change the methodName nor reimplement the default runTest() method."

Answer (score -1):

You can run it like this:

```
python -m unittest <your-module-name>
```

I don't fully understand why it works though.